# with a conscience

Tags: phrase-meaning, idiom-meaning

[(From *The Wrecker* by Robert Louis Stevenson and Lloyd Osbourne, Chapter XVI, published 1892)](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Wrecker_(Stevenson)/Chapter_16)

Passage 252

> Then I remembered that I had a friend on board, and stepped to the companion.
>
> “Gentlemen,” said I, “only a few moments more: but these, I regret to say, I must make more tedious still by removing your companion. It is indispensable that I should have a word or two with Captain Nares.”
>
> Both the smugglers were afoot at once, protesting. The business, they declared, must be despatched at once; they had run risk enough, **with a conscience**; and they must either finish now, or go.
>
> “The choice is yours, gentlemen,” said I, “and, I believe, the eagerness. I am not yet sure that I have anything in your way; even if I have, there are a hundred things to be considered; and I assure you it is not at all my habit to do business with a pistol to my head.”

What do you take "with a conscience" to mean in this context? I can but find the literal meaning, I'm afraid, but that doesn't work there in my opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the context, it looks like a variant of **in conscience**, which Oxfoird Languages defines as

*by any fair or reasonable standard.*

*"how can we in all conscience justify the charging of fees for such a service?"*